# echo both users

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, loops

The code at the bottom of this post currently echoes:

> **Name:** Spongebob Squarepants
>
> **Description:** I live in a pineapple under the sea.
>
> **Role:** editor

But there are two users in "wp_usermeta". It's only echoing one. The result needs to look like this:

> **Name:** wp_dev_05
>
> **Description:** My name is Chris Topher! I like long walks on the beach and bags of pork rinds.
>
> **Role:** administrator
>
> **Name:** Spongebob Squarepants
>
> **Description:** I live in a pineapple under the sea.
>
> **Role:** editor

```
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT `meta_value` as `value` FROM `wp_usermeta` WHERE `meta_key` = 'first_name'") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $first_name = $row["value"];
}

$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT `meta_value` as 'value' FROM `wp_usermeta` WHERE `meta_key` = 'last_name'") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $last_name = $row["value"];
}

$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT `meta_value` as 'value' FROM `wp_usermeta` WHERE `meta_key` = 'description'") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $description = $row["value"];
}

$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT `meta_value` as 'value' FROM `wp_usermeta` WHERE `meta_key` = 'wp_capabilities'") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $role_array = $row["value"];
}

//Creates wp_capability meta_value as a string.
$role= unserialize($role_array);
    while ($role_index = current($role)) {
        if ($role_index == 1) {
            $user_role = key($role);
        }

    next($role);
}
        echo '<b>Name: </b>';
        echo $first_name . ' ';
        echo $last_name . '</br>';
        echo '<b>Description: </b>';
        echo $description . '</br>';
        echo '<b>Role: </b>';
        echo $user_role . '</br>';
```

How can I write this to get my desired result? Thanks for any help!

Comment: You over write the value on every loop. Store it in an array or concatenate it. Example `$first_name[] = $row["value"];` Then at the end do `print_r($first_name);` to see the array populated.

Comment: Have you tried doing it in a single query. Then just fetch it all?

Comment: @chris85 thanks! It worked! I had to move a lot of stuff around (there was a lot of code that I didn't post on here) but now it's working perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just do it in one single query? Just replace the necessary table and column name, and variables/values/parameters to be bind in your query:

```
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT first_name, last_name, description, role FROM `wp_usermeta`
                              WHERE `first_name` = '$first_name'
                                OR `last_name` = '$last_name'
                                OR `description` = '$description'
                                OR `role` = '$role'") or die(mysqli_error($conn));

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
  echo "<b>Name: </b>".$row["first_name"]." ".$row["last_name"]."<br>";
  echo "<b>Description: </b>".$row["description"]."<br>";
  echo "<b>Role: </b>".$row["role"]."<br>";
}
```

Comment: thanks! I got it going with chris85's suggestion, and then came back to find your answer. I think I'll use your code when I go back and tidy everything up.